# Word 2010: Multiple copies of a merged record on a label

Tags: merge, label

We'd like to print 4 copies of each merged label on a 6 up label form (Avery 5164) and then go on to the next record. How do we say "repeat record 1" in the merge, then say next record after the fourth?

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I print multiple copies of a label when merging?

1. Open the source document.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to display the field codes.
3. Make sure that the `{ NEXT }` field appears only after the number of desired labels.

   As you want 4 copies of each label, then `{ NEXT }` should appear only at the beginning of the 5th, 9th, 13th, 17th, ... labels.

---

> If you display the source document and then press Alt+F9 to display the field codes in the document. You will see that for each label except the first one, Word includes a { NEXT } field at the beginning of the label. To print multiple copies of the labels, simply remove the desired number of { NEXT } fields. For each { NEXT } field you remove, Word will print that label using the data in the same data record as used by the previous label. (Remember, as well, that Word puts the labels together from left to right, then from top to bottom.)
>
> For instance, let's say that Word formatted your source document for Avery 5160 labels, which are three across and ten rows per sheet. If you want three copies of each label, simply remove the { NEXT } fields from each label in columns two and three. Thus, a { NEXT } field will appear only in the first label of each row, with the exception of the first row, where a { NEXT } is always assumed by Word. To create your actual labels, simply merge the source document with the data source to create a new document that has your labels. You will see that each label is repeated three times.
>
> To create a different quantity of labels, simply make sure that the { NEXT } field appears only after the number of desired labels. This means that if you want five copies of each label, then { NEXT } should appear only at the beginning of the sixth, eleventh, sixteenth, twenty-first, and twenty-sixth labels.
>
> The downside to this approach is that the number of labels you print must be a factor of the number of labels on the sheet. In the case of the Avery 5160 labels, the number 30 (the number of labels per sheet) must be evenly divisible by the number of copies you want. For instance, you could print 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, or 15 labels and fill up each sheet. If you use a different number, such as 7, which is not evenly divisible (7 times 4 is 28, which is the closest you can get), then you must remove all the fields from the last two labels of the sheet so they will print out blank.

Source [Printing Multiple Label Copies when Merging](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T009888_Printing_Multiple_Label_Copies_when_Merging.html)

Comment: That's very helpful - I knew there must be a way.  There isn't a workaround for the "non-divisible" problem?  I've got 60 or so sets of 4 labels to print, and the size we need comes as 6 up.  The merge (from Excel) could all be run in one shot by moving to the next page - can I lay out two pages for a total of 3 sets of 4, or will it override the merge fields to do "Next" at the top of the second page?  The only other option is to run as 2 each, and then print the whole thing twice.

Comment: @Gracie I would do a small test run and see if 2 pages of 3 sets of 4 works or not. At worst you only waste 2 pages of labels...